# find and print specific url or web address using file_get_contents

Tags: php

I have file websites.txt and this file has text not arranged (it is a source html code) and I'd like to search this source code and find urls that match example.com/sub/text (so any url start with example.com/sub/text should be matched) and print/echo them.

I am using file_get_contents and need to print only that matches http://www.example.com/sub/text/

I tried preg_match but I do not know how to create a pattern from (http://www.example.com/sub/text/)

Comment: WHAT are you trying? please explain to people who don't know what you are doing

Comment: Well, I have  file websites.txt and this file has text not arranged (it is a source html code) and I'd like to search this source code and find urls that match http://www.example.com/sub/text/ (so any url start with http://www.example.com/sub/text/ should be matched) and print/echo them. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you provide .txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $pattern="%http://www.+[a-z]+/+[a-z]+/+[a-z]+/%";

if(preg_match_all($pattern,$content,$match)) {


    print_r($match);


}
```

pdf -> `something like this: $pattern="%http://www.+[a-z]+/+[a-z]+/+[a-z]+.pdf%";`

Comment: nevermind, what if I wanted to print/output only links that ends in pdf example, www.mysite.com/store/file.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> Check this for understanding purpose..copy and test in your side..

```
$contentss = file_get_contents("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?LinkName=pubmed_pubmed&from_uid=18032633" );

preg_match('/<div class="rprt">(.*)<\/div>/',$contentss,$matches);  
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: I need the pattern for http://www.example.com/sub/text/ could you write me preg_match expression using above pattren as example?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.